# Obj-C/iOS - Adding rows to a dynamic uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsarray

So, I'm creating an app and it has a tableview with contacts in it. Users add contacts from their contact list.

The problem is; I can add people, but they don't appear until a restart.

I've searched other questions/answers but none helped so far.

This is my add person action button:

```
 - (IBAction)addPerson:(id)sender {
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController* picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I used 2 mutable arrays, one for storing names, other for storing numbers.

And here is the nav controller:

```
-(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person{

NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[defaults objectForKey:@"numbers"]];
people =  [[NSMutableArray alloc]  initWithArray:[defaults objectForKey:@"people"]];

if(people.count == 0 && numbers.count == 0){
    numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    people =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

This is where the table should update itself, but it doesn't.

```
NSString *contactName = CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person));
NSString* nameField = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", contactName ? contactName : @"No Name"];
ABMultiValueRef phoneRecord = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
CFStringRef phoneNumber = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneRecord, 0);
NSString* phoneField = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)phoneNumber;
CFRelease(phoneRecord);

**[tableview beginUpdates];**
[people addObject:nameField];
[numbers addObject:phoneField];

[defaults setObject:people forKey:@"people"];;
[defaults setObject:numbers forKey:@"numbers"];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

 //[tableview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; 
 //since it's a dynamic table, I'm not sure if this works.
**[tableview endUpdates];**
return NO;
}
```

Am I missing some other tableview update?
If so, where should that go?

Any kind of help would be much appreciated.
If I run the code without the **'ed lines (updates), it successfully adds but requires restart to appear.
If I run the code with the **'ed lines, or using *beginUpdates*, I get NSInternalInconsistencyException, invalid number of rows in section 0.

Btw, tableview and tableView are two different UITableViews.

Answer (score 0):

You should also update new rows count in `numberOfRowsInSection`.

```
[people addObject:nameField];
[numbers addObject:phoneField];
[defaults setObject:people forKey:@"people"];;
[defaults setObject:numbers forKey:@"numbers"];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

[tableview beginUpdates];

[tableview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(int)people.count withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

[tableview endUpdates];


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //if (section == n) {
    //    return ...
    //}
    return (int)people.count;        
}
```

Comment: I thought about that, too.
But I don't have a clue how can I do it.

Comment: At 
[tableview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:people.count withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
I get "implicit conversion of 'nsuinteger' (aka 'unsigned int') to 'NSArray *' is disallowed with ARC

Comment: I'm not sure how can I add (int) as answer.
I changed that part of the code to 
[tableview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:  **(int)** people.count withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

And all I got was 'Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'int' to parameter of type 'NSArray *'